# Override class of parameter in method if it extends that of parameter used in abstract method

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class

Suppose I have the following four classess, out of which two are abstract and two are concrete: `Abstract1`, `Concrete1`, `Abstract2`, `Concrete2`.

`Concrete1` extends `Abstract1` and `Concrete2` extends `Abstract2`.

Suppose I have the following four classess, out of which two are abstract and two are concrete: `AbstractProp`, `ConcreteProp`, `AbstractClass`, `ConcreteClass`.

`ConcreteProp` extends `AbstractProp` and `ConcreteClass` extends `AbstractClass`.

The code for `AbstractClass` would look like the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected AbstractProp someProperty;

    public abstract void setProperty(AbstractProp someProperty);
}
```

When implementing `ConcreteClass`, I want to be able to do something like this (keep in mind that `AbstractProp` extends `ConcreteProp):

```
public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass {
    @Override
    public void setProperty(ConcreteProp someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

But this last bit of code isn't valid because the classes of the parameters (`AbstractProp` and `ConcreteProp`) in `setProperty()` differ, making the `@Override` annotation invalid. Is there a way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do here, perhaps using generics and/or wildcards?

**NOTE:** I'm aware that this type of naming is bad practice and the code is oversimplistic, I'm not actually using it and this is just an example to keep the question as simple as possible.

Comment: That's exactly what `<P extends AbstractProp>` is for.

Comment: But I'm not sure on how to implement it without causing errors.
When implementing the method in `ConcreteClass`, I want to force the parameter class into being of `ConcreteProp`, not just `<P extends AbstractProp>`. If this is possible, can you please provide an example, possibly using the code in the original post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you introduce generics on the `AbstractClass` you can achieve what you are requesting.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T extends AbstractProp> {
    protected T someProperty;

    public void setProperty(T someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

And then specify that you want `ConcreteProp` to be the type you want in your `ConcreteClass`.

```
public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass<ConcreteProp> {

    @Override
    public void setProperty(final ConcreteProp someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you a lot!